# How to calculate the following curve integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let $E$ be the boundary of triangle cut by three coordinate planes of plane $x + y + z = 1$, and set $T$ is
$$T=\{(x,y,z)\in E|x,y,z\in\mathbb Q\}.$$
Define vector valued function $\vec{f}$ to satisfy:
$$\vec{f}=
         \begin{cases}
          (x,y,z),& (x,y,z\in E-T) \\
          (3,1,2).& (x,y,z\in T)  \\
         \end{cases}$$
Calculate the integral
$$I=\oint_{E}\vec{f}\cdot\vec{n}.(\vec{n}=(\mathrm{d}x, \mathrm{d}y,  \mathrm{d}z))$$
This is a piece of homework left by our teacher.What I think of now is to express $x, y, z$ with the reduced fraction $\frac{m}{n}(n\in\mathbb{N}^+,m\in\mathbb{Z},(m,n)=1)$.
Then use Riemann sum to calculate, but it's too difficult for me. Is there any other solution? Thank you.

Comment: Is this in the context of Riemann integral or Lebesgue integral? That will make a difference in the answer.

Comment: @Sungjin Kim Thank you sir, this is in the context of Riemann integral.